# WPF Chain effect on an image

Tags: c#, wpf

**The Task**

For an image processing component, I want to adjust the brightness, the saturation and the sharpness of an image, depending on some input values. I work within a WPF application. As input, I have an image loaded in an `Image` control.

**What I've already done**

I was able to control the brightness and the saturation of the image using HLSL and a `ShaderEffect` implementation, which adjusts the RGB values of each pixel of the source image.

**The Problem**

The problem now is that, after applying my so called `BrightnessSaturationEffect` to the `Image` control, I now want to control the sharpness - basically, I would now add a `BlurEffect` to the image.

Appearently, when using the old `BitmapEffect` classes, there was a possibility to chain effects using a `BitmapEffectGroup`, but the API is marked as obsolete.

Is there a possibility to apply more than one effect to `Image.Effect`, i.e. chain effects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there is no replacement for the `BitmapEffectGroup` available. You would have to provide all of your effects using a single `Effect` implementation.

As a workaround, I was able to "stack" my effects using a simple `Border` around my `ImageControl`, where the `Border` gets the `BlurEffect´ and the child image control holds the shader effect.